# Custom tick labels for colormap

Tags: matplotlib, geopandas

I have a plot including a colormap with 3 colors.

[image]

```
import geopandas
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
    )

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('PiYG', 3)

world.plot(
    column='pop_est',
    ax=ax,
    legend=True,
    cmap=cmap
    )
```

How can I add custom tick marks to the colormap/legend? `legend_kwds={'ticks': ['Low','Medium','High']}` yields `TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'` and `cmap.ax.set_xticklabels(['Low', 'Medium', 'High'])` yields `AttributeError: 'LinearSegmentedColormap' object has no attribute 'ax'`.

Comment: First of all, the colormap is not the colorbar. So the first step is to find the colorbar. Then set bot the ticks (you need three, not six) and the ticklabels.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with your question, but using a different color for medium population than oceans would be wise. Even though there are no such countries by your scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you will need to set a separate colorbar yourself to achieve what you need. In your code, keep legend as false, then create a new colorbar as you need... Updated code below.

```
import geopandas
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors ## Added newly

world = geopandas.read_file(
    geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres')
    )

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

cmap = cm.get_cmap('PiYG', 3)

world.plot(
    column='pop_est',
    ax=ax,
    legend=False,  ## Note - changed to False
    cmap=cmap,
    )

## Create new Colorbar with info you want...
norm=colors.Normalize(vmin=world.pop_est.min(), vmax=world.pop_est.max())
cbar=plt.cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.get_cmap('PiYG', 3))
axCbar=fig.colorbar(cbar, ax=ax)
axCbar.set_ticks([200000000,700000000,1200000000])
axCbar.set_ticklabels(["Low","Medium","High"])
```

[image]